# Is it Ok to call method on NULL pointer instance of a class?

Tags: c++

This C++ code works for my platform and compiler (Windows, GCC 4.7):

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
public:

    /* ... */

    int size() const
    {
        if ( this == NULL ) {
            return 0;
        }
        return m_size;
    }

private:
    int m_size;
};

int main()
{
    A* a = NULL;

    printf( "%d\n", a->size() );
}
```

But is this code valid standard C++ and portable?
Is it Ok for method to accept this == NULL?

Comment: NO, IT'S NOT OK.!!!!!!

Comment: This is undefined behaviour

Comment: I didn't read the standard but I can't imagine something that says "It's OK to call a method from a null variable".

Comment: `if ( this == NULL ) {`   o_O

Comment: This is wrong. Don't do this. Ever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not OK. Any dereference of a NULL pointer is undefined behavior. It happens to work because it's not a virtual function (therefore there's no jump through the object's vtable), but that's not an excuse for doing what you're doing.

Comment: Actually it's a little more complex than that, but the end result is that — for the time being at least — we can more or less conclude that it's _probably_ UB.

Comment: It doesn't need to be virtual to crash and burn.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: In practice, with no member accesses, it pretty much does.